# What’s the four wires to the intercom bell / speaker?

Tags: electrical, wiring, doorbell

[image]

Hi, I had an old intercom system and I removed the bell/chime at the front door. I am now looking to install a ring door bell. But I have to deal with the 4 wires, which one is what? How do I know for sure? I know the max power is 24v because the guy who removed the old system told me that.
[image]

Comment: The NEC doesn't specify colors for most circuits below 50v, your best bet is to trace the wires and see how or if they are still connected to a transformer.

Comment: find the other end of the cable

Comment: Ah ok. Do you know if a multimeter can help? Not sure where the two ends will go in this case!

Comment: The other end goes to the intercom chime.

Comment: I added picture of the ‘other end’ of the wiring. But it’s not really the other end, the intercom is wired to other speaker / mic in other rooms. This is the only easily accessible part - the chime for the bell.

Comment: If you know how to use a multimeter you could test for AC volts. You would need to disconnect the wires at the bell to make sure you don't read open circuit voltage through the solenoid.

Comment: It's possible the button that was part door intercom was not part of the intercom system, and the wiring to the doorbell is still intact. You might try removing the wirenuts and bumping tips of wires together to see if a combination rings the bell then install following RING instructions.

Comment: It's also possible, but unlikely, that the transformer is in a j-box behind the chime.

Comment: What can possibly happen if I bump two wrong wire tips together ? Is the idea to find the two right wire tips that rings the bell and use the same one for ring?

Comment: Bumping yellow wire tip with any other wire tip causes the intercom chime to ring. Does that mean I should use yellow and ANY other wire to connect to ring door bell?

Comment: I would verify what voltage you have available. The controls in intercoms usually have power supply’s  That convert  to DC . Code calls out black is negative and red is positive. But we do not know how the system was wired. Without verification you really don’t know if there is still power there at all when the intercom was removed the supply may have been removed.

Comment: The red/black shows 0 ..and was connected to the speaker of the old intercom. The orange/yellow shows 20V DC..!